# Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: unknown keys in `extends`

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines, gitlab-ci.yml

My code for the pipeline is:

```
include:
 - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
 - init
 - validate
 - build
 - deploy
init:
 extends: .init
validate:
 extends: .validate
build:
 extends: .build
deploy:
 extends: .deploy
 dependencies:
   - build
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:  
init: unknown keys in extends (.init)  
You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint
```

Comment: What is your .init section?

Comment: I'm guessing it comes from the template Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.ym in the 'include' section. The reference is https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
Although I don't see any .init section in that file
What would you suggest?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Is the code you shared for your `.gitlab-ci.yml` only a snippet?
Where do you define your `.init`, `.validate`, `.build`, and `.deploy` job templates?

The pipeline template `Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml` that you inherit from only has the following jobs defined that you can extend:

- `.terraform:fmt`
- `.terraform:validate`
- `.terraform:build`
- `.terraform:deploy`
- `.terraform:destroy`

You can make use of `https://gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/-/ci/lint` to [validate the syntax](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html) of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: This is correct answer, but in gitlab's examples used terraform:init.